# Glass VoiceListener causes Illegal Argument exception

Tags: java, android, google-glass, voice-recognition, google-gdk

So I had the GlassVoice.jar VoiceListener working on Glass until I changed a few things.  One was that I upgraded Glass to XE18.11, and the other was that I moved the VoiceListener to its own thread outside of the main activity.  Now when I run the code, I get the following error:

> 06-24 12:46:35.844: E/AndroidRuntime(5425): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-24 12:46:35.844: E/AndroidRuntime(5425): Process: com.myapp, PID: 5425
>   06-24 12:46:35.844: E/AndroidRuntime(5425): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI type: 1279544898
>   06-24 12:46:35.844: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1469)
>   06-24 12:46:35.844: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
>   06-24 12:46:35.844: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at com.google.glass.voice.IVoiceService$Stub$Proxy.setConfig(Unknown Source)
>   06-24 12:46:35.844: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at com.google.glass.input.VoiceInputHelper.setVoiceConfig(Unknown Source)
>   06-24 12:46:35.844: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at com.myapp.voice_recognition.VoiceRecognitionThread$MyVoiceListener.onVoiceServiceConnected(VoiceRecognitionThread.java:183)
>   06-24 12:46:35.844: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at com.google.glass.input.VoiceInputHelper.dispatchVoiceServiceConnected(Unknown Source)
>   06-24 12:46:35.844: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at com.google.glass.input.VoiceInputHelper.access$400(Unknown Source)
>   06-24 12:46:35.844: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at com.google.glass.input.VoiceInputHelper$2.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
>   06-24 12:46:35.844: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   06-24 12:46:35.844: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
>   06-24 12:46:35.844: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
>   06-24 12:46:35.844: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-24 12:46:35.844: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   06-24 12:46:35.844: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   06-24 12:46:35.844: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
>   06-24 12:46:35.844: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I thought something might have changed with the jar because of the software upgrade, so I repulled the GlassVoice apk and redid the apk->jar process, but when I use the new jar I can't even upload the app because I run out of memory.  I don't really know why that happens.

Any thoughts? The code is the same as when it worked, but if you need to see it I can provide it.

UPDATE: I used git to go back to before I moved the listener to a new thread.  This version worked 100% on XE12.  It now does not work, same error.  Same memory issues when trying to use the new jar.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I was still having no luck getting the GlassVoice.jar code that I got from XE12 to work, so I tackled the problem of running out of memory when using the new GlassVoice.jar I pulled from the XE18.11.  I increased Eclipse's memory allowance to recommended levels and it still didn't work.  I doubled the recommended levels and it finally went through.  I have voice commands back.